# plotting pwelch with log axis

Tags: matlab, plot, spectral

I'm using `pwelch` to plot a power spectral density. I want to use the format

```
pwelch=(x,window,noverlap,nfft,fs,'onesided')
```

but with a log scale on the x axis.

I've also tried

```
[P,F]=(x,window,noverlap,nfft,fs);
plot(F,P)
```

but it doesn't give the same resulting plot as above. Therefore,

```
semilogx(F,P)
```

isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so to start, I've never heard of this function or this method. However, I was able to generate the same plot that the function produced using output arguments instead. I ran the example from the `help` text.

```
EXAMPLE:
   Fs = 1000;   t = 0:1/Fs:.296;
   x = cos(2*pi*t*200)+randn(size(t));  % A cosine of 200Hz plus noise
   pwelch(x,[],[],[],Fs,'twosided'); % Uses default window, overlap & NFFT.
```

That produces this plot:
[image: Desired Pic]

I then did: `plot(bar,10*log10(foo)); grid on;` to produce the linear version (same exact plot, minus labels):

[image: pic1]

or

`semilogx(bar,10*log10(foo)); grid on;` for the log scale on the x-axis. 
[image: pic2]

I don't like that the x-scale is sampled linearly but displayed logarithmically (that's a word right?), but it seems to look ok.

Good enough?

Comment: Yep, same basic output as giving pwelch outputs i.e. [...]=pwelch(..) and then plotting the results, but a cleaner way of doing it. Thanks. Say, if you haven't heard of pwelch before, do you know of any other functions for making power spectral densities?

Comment: Take the fourier transform and plot that.